# ImportError when call a pytorch (python) model in matlab

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, pytorch

When I try to call a pytorch python model in matlab script, I met an ImportError: "dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS".

This is a simple example of the problem:

```
% matlab script test.m

clear classes
if count(py.sys.path,'') == 0
    insert(py.sys.path,int32(0),'');
end
mod = py.importlib.import_module('test_python');
py.reload(mod);
py.test_python.myfunction;
```

```
# python script test_python.py

import torch.optim as optim

def myfunction():
    print 'hello world 2!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunction()
```

The  the error message

```
Error using __init__><module> (line 84)
Python Error: ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

Error in test_python><module> (line 3)
import torch.optim as optim

Error in __init__>import_module (line 37)
    __import__(name)
```

The python script can be run independently, without error. 
If do not import torch (delete the line "import torch.optim as optim"), there will be no error.
I am running MATLAB 2017a, Python 2.7 and Pytorch 1.0.1.post2

Comment: Do you have any other Python versions installed on your system? Could it be that Matlab is searchin in a different path for the python version?

Comment: Yes, I also have python 3.5 on my system, but the default version is 2.7. So, what should I do next?

Comment: can you run both python2 and python3 in a shell and see if you can import PyTorch in both? It should obviously only be available in the python environment where you installed it (and Matlab is calling it), but it might be a versioning conflict.